# Use Tkinter with Tornado Websockets. How can I get both running?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter, tornado

I want to create a simple python application, that shows in a TKinter Window   what it receives from a Websocket.

My Problem is, I cant get both running side by side. For the communication I would use a queue, but i stuck one step before.

My plan is to run the tornado loop in a extra thread, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I search for solutions, but i didn't find anything useful.

Heres my test application:

```
import threading
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import Tkinter

class TornadoThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        application = tornado.web.Application([(r'/',WSHandler)])
        application.listen(9090)
    def run(self):
        print "Start a tornado"
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'connection opened...'
        self.write_message("The server says: 'Hello'. Connection was accepted.")

    def on_message(self, message):
        #self.write_message("The server says: " + message + " back at you")
        print 'received:', message

    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed...'



TornadoThread = TornadoThread()

# Start new Threads
TornadoThread.start()

top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.mainloop()
```

`

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't very helpful. Does it crash? Does it return incorrect results? Does it fail to run?

Comment: It runs and the tkinter window opens. But i cant connect to the websocket. The "start a tornado" is also printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing parentheses in the call to `IOLoop.instance().start()`. With that fixed (and a few other changes, fixing the indent of the run method and changing `myThread()` to `TornadoThread()`), your code works for me.

Comment: Hi Ben,
you are right, the missing parentheses after the start-call was the problem. I edited the code and now it works. Thank you very much for your help.